# Is there are a way to replace python import with actual sources?

Tags: python, compilation, python-import

I am having python files with the import statements which I would like to replace into the actual code placed in the foo.py.

For instance, with the `in` file:

```
from foo import Bar

bar = Bar()
print bar
```

I would like to `out` file  below:

```
# source of Bar class.

bar = Bar()
print bar
```

How can I perform such imports replacement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use the [ast.NodeTransformer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeTransformer) in order to accomplish such import replacement.

[AST](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#module-ast) provides way to interact with the python code as with the trees of the Python abstract syntax grammar.

The [ast.NodeTransformer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeTransformer) can be used to traverse through your code and identifying [ImportFrom](https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nodes.html?highlight=Import#ImportFrom) node ( the code parsed with ast is represented as the tree of nodes). After identifying [ImportFrom](https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nodes.html?highlight=Import#ImportFrom) node you can replace it with group of nodes which correspond to the **source code of the `Bar` class**, which lead to your goal.

Please see code below which describes approach described below:

```
from ast import NodeTransformer, parse, fix_missing_locations

import astor


class FromImportTransformer(NodeTransformer):
    """ General from imports transformer. """


    def visit_ImportFrom(self, node):
        new_node = self.get_sources(node)
        # Replace node.
        fix_missing_locations(node)
        return node

    def get_sources(self, node):
        """ Accepts importFrom node and build new ast tree from the sources described in import. """
        raise NotImplemented


def transform_imports(self, source_file):
    with open(source_file) as original_sources:
        sources = original_sources.read()
    root = parse(sources, source_file)
    try:
        root = FromImportTransformer().visit(root)
    except Exception as exc:
        raise exc
    sources = astor.to_source(root, indent_with=' ' * 4, add_line_information=False)
    return processed_sources


path_to_in_sources = '/tmp/in.py'
path_to_out_sources = '/tmp/out.py'
processed_sources = transform_imports(path_to_in_sources)


with open(path_to_out_sources, 'wb+') as out:
    out.write(processed_sources)
```

**NOTE 1**: I suggest you to use the [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) in order to compile  sources with correct globals and locals dict.

**NOTE 2**: Take into account that you will need to handle nested imports ( if foo file stores imports you wish to replace to).

**NOTE 3**: I've used [astor](https://pypi.org/project/astor/) to convert code from ast tree into the python code.